# Error _SDL_Main SDL Mac Xcode 6 C Language

Tags: c, macos, xcode6, sdl

Trying to compile SDL on MAC using XCode and C Language

While trying to compile my program, the following error occurs:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_SDL_main", referenced
>   from:
>         -[SDLMain applicationDidFinishLaunching:] in SDLMain.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker
>   command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: ...with minimal example. And do it fast, the vote-to-close is nearly ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your main program is called `Main.cpp`, try compiling it like this:

```
g++ Main.cpp -o main $(sdl2-config --cflags --libs)
```

and `sdl2-config` will generate all the correct compiler and linker flags you need for you.

If you are interested, you can see what it thinks the correct settings are with:

```
sdl2-config --cflags --libs
```

I get:

```
-I/usr/local/include/SDL2 -D_THREAD_SAFE -L/usr/local/lib -lSDL2
```

Comment: Thanks for you answering Mark. Im not using SDL2, Im using SDL1.2 and my main program is Main.c. 
I think the problem is with SDLmain.m.. but im not sure at all

Comment: This is perfect, this got it working for me on MacOS. Thank you