# Undefined SDL2 symbols on arm64 Mac?

Tags: c++, macos, sdl-2, apple-m1, undefined-symbol

I set up SDL2 and tried to run it with sample code:

```
// On linux compile with:
// g++ -std=c++17 main.cpp -o prog -lSDL2

// C++ Standard Libraries
#include <iostream>

// Third-party library
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]){

    // Create a window data type
    // This pointer will point to the 
    // window that is allocated from SDL_CreateWindow
    SDL_Window* window=nullptr;

    // Initialize the video subsystem.
    // If it returns less than 1, then an
    // error code will be received.
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0){
        std::cout << "SDL could not be initialized: " <<
                  SDL_GetError();
    }else{
        std::cout << "SDL video system is ready to go\n";
    }

    // Request a window to be created for our platform
    // The parameters are for the title, x and y position,
    // and the width and height of the window.
    window = SDL_CreateWindow("C++ SDL2 Window",
            0,
            2500,
            640,
            480,
            SDL_WINDOW_SHOWN);

    // We add a delay in order to see that our window
    // has successfully popped up.
    SDL_Delay(3000);

    // We destroy our window. We are passing in the pointer
    // that points to the memory allocated by the 
    // 'SDL_CreateWindow' function. Remember, this is
    // a 'C-style' API, we don't have destructors.
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    
    // We safely uninitialize SDL2, that is, we are
    // taking down the subsystems here before we exit
    // our program.
    SDL_Quit();
    return 0;
}
```

...but I am getting an error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_SDL_CreateWindow", referenced from:
      _main in gui-67ced6.o
  "_SDL_Delay", referenced from:
      _main in gui-67ced6.o
  "_SDL_DestroyWindow", referenced from:
      _main in gui-67ced6.o
  "_SDL_GetError", referenced from:
      _main in gui-67ced6.o
  "_SDL_Init", referenced from:
      _main in gui-67ced6.o
  "_SDL_Quit", referenced from:
      _main in gui-67ced6.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I am running this on Apple's M1 Pro

I keep seeing this error and everywhere I looked the only solution I am getting is on Xcode. I am trying to run this using VS Code.

Comment: Looks like your SDL library was not built for Apple Silicon.  Find the `libSDL2.a` file and do `lipo -info libSDL2.a` to verify this.

Comment: Yep, there's no libSDL2.a file. What do I do now?

Comment: No, there is an `SDL` library there somewhere otherwise the error would have been different.  It's found one but it doesn't contain the CPU arch you are building for.

Comment: What to do now?  Well what is it you want to do? I wouldn't start graphics programming using SDL if I could help it.

Comment: I can't find it. Could you give me pointers to where it could be?

Comment: Well if you want to continue using SDL then I would use a version from homebrew and I would use `cmake` to manage the build. Try this tutorial: https://wolfgang-ziegler.com/blog/sdl-cmake-osx

Comment: @trojanfoe that URL annoyingly uses the cargo cult-y way. The sdl2-config.cmake file also exposes a nice `SDL2::SDL2` target you can just link to and have everything work.

Comment: @Botje Yeah I'm sure there are other tutorials out there.  This is more than can be reasonably answered on SO tho.

Comment: I am using Python/Java for GUI from now on

Comment: I install with **homebrew** and then use this https://stackoverflow.com/a/32446219/2836621

Comment: Build the SDL library from source code.